# Google Chrome not setting Authorization cookie on unsecured localhost

Tags: google-chrome

When I log in to my localhost website, Google Chrome does not **usually** set the Authorization cookie. Sometimes it does, and will keep doing so until I shut everything down, then it's a crap-shoot if it will next time.

Everything works fine in all other browsers, including Brave.

My website is not secure, i.e. not https.

I've looked at all other questions I can find on SO, none solved issue.

Anyone know what's going on here, is there a work-around?

Comment: Google Chrome does not set an authorization cookie, because of your web server. I would like to know what kind of a web server you are using and also have you tried to create an SSL certification?

Comment: @Kektuto I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 behind IIS express or whatever gets loaded with Visual Studio. Think Kestrel's in the mix too. Know how to use ASP.NET Core, not too bright beyond that. Yes, things work fine when i go SSL, but in production will not have a cert, so it's a pain, want to make sure things are  working as expected by not using a cert on my dev box.